# Making babies in "x" families

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm attempting a code wherein you put in an input of x families, then the program should have each family have babies (with a 50/50 chance to have one of either sex) until one of each sex each achieved. Then, it should output the average, the number of families with 2, 3, 4, and 5 or more babies, and the most common number of babies it took to achieve the goal. I believe I have messed up after the while statement (somewhere in the cluster of if statements). Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
public class BoysAndGirls {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int families = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int boy = 0;
        int girl = 0;
        int fam2 = 0;
        int fam3 = 0;
        int fam4 = 0;
        int fam5 = 0;
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < families; i++) {
            while ((boy <= 1) || (girl <= 1)) {
                if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                    boy = boy + 1;
                } else {
                    girl = girl + 1;
                }
                total++;
            }

            if (total == 2) {
                fam2++;
            }
            if (total == 3) {
                fam3++;
            }
            if (total == 4) {
                fam4++;
            }
            if (total >= 5) {
                fam5++;
            }
        }

        double average = total / families;
        System.out.println("Average: " + average + " babies were had to get at least one of each sex.");
        System.out.println("Number of families with 2 children: " + fam2);
        System.out.println("Number of families with 3 children: " + fam3);
        System.out.println("Number of families with 4 children: " + fam4);
        System.out.println("Number of families with 5 or more children: " + fam5);
        //System.out.println("The most common number of children was " + common + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zenadix Yes. I'm looking for any help I can get, vague or not. I couldn't find time to get to the lab here for help.

Comment: making babies = homework, I've got the wrong degree :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so there's a few small changes you should make.

You should have another variable, let's say `currentTotal` that keeps track of current **total number of kids for a single family**, and use the other variable `total` to keep track of the **total number of kids for all families**.

Also in the beginning of your loop, you need to reset the counters `boy`, `girl`, `currentTotal` to zero since they count information for a single family.

In the end when you calculate the average number of kids, you need to [typecast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) your `int total` to a `double` since integer division isn't very exact.

Instead of:

```
double average = total / families;
```

Put:

```
double average = (double) total / families;
```

With all these modifications applied to your code, we get:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int families = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int boy;
    int girl;
    int fam2 = 0;
    int fam3 = 0;
    int fam4 = 0;
    int fam5 = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int currentTotal;
    for (int i=0; i < families; i++){
        currentTotal = 0;
        boy = 0;
        girl = 0;
        while ( (boy < 1) || (girl < 1) ){
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                boy = boy + 1;
            }
            else {
                girl = girl + 1;
            }
            currentTotal++;
            total++;
        }
        if (currentTotal == 2){
            fam2++;
        }
        if (currentTotal == 3){
            fam3++;
        }
        if (currentTotal == 4){
            fam4++;
        }
        if (currentTotal >= 5){
            fam5++;
        }
    }
    double average = (double) total / families;
    System.out.println("Average: " + average + " babies were had to get at least one of each sex.");
    System.out.println("Number of families with 2 children: " + fam2);
    System.out.println("Number of families with 3 children: " + fam3);
    System.out.println("Number of families with 4 children: " + fam4);
    System.out.println("Number of families with 5 or more children: " + fam5);
    //System.out.println("The most common number of children was " + common + ".");
}
```

Sample output when input is 10

```
Average: 2.7 babies were had to get at least one of each sex.
Number of families with 2 children: 7
Number of families with 3 children: 2
Number of families with 4 children: 0
Number of families with 5 or more children: 1
```

**EDIT:**

To find the most common number of babies, you just have to find the **largest value out of all the `fam` variables**. You can do this your own way, my suggestion for you is the following. Change your code at the top to have an array of size 4:

```
int[] fams = new int[4];
```

instead of each of the fam variables (`fam2`, `fam3`, `fam4`, `fam5`).

Then in your loop, no matter what the currentTotal is, you can cover all the cases (replace all the `if` statements) with:

```
if(currentTotal >= 5) { 
    fams[3]++;  // 5 or more children. index 3 is the 4th element
} else {
    fams[currentTotal - 2]++; // currentTotal - 2 because we are offsetting by 2
}
```

Then you would find your most common element by finding the largest value in the `fams` array.

```
int common = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < fams.length; i++) {
    if(common < fams[i]) {
        common = fams[i];
    }
}
// at this point, common would hold the most common number of kids
```

Comment: in fact if you want to simplify even further - boy, girl and currentTotal could all be declared at the start of the for loop, instead of outside.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your input. I did the suggestions you provided but now the only numbers that are being used are 4 or 5 or more. There are two or three children. Is there a way for me to speak to you directly? or do I have to just edit my question?

Comment: @nem "fams[currentTotal - 1]++" should be "fams[currentTotal - 2]++", because you are offsetting the array by 2, not the standard 1.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to reset the `boy` and `girl` count before the `while` loop.  The second time through the `for` loop, boy and girl are at least 1 already, so will skip straight past the `while` loop.

```
 for (int i=0; i < families; i++){
       boy = 0;
       girl = 0;
       while ( (boy <= 1) || (girl <= 1) ){
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                boy = boy + 1;
            } else {
                girl = girl + 1;
            }
       }
       total = boy + girl;
       .....
 }
```

Just noticed as well, that you never reset `total`.  The best way to do this is not increment it during the loop and simply re-assign it based on the sum of `boy + girl`, after the `while` loop.